# XAMPP errors when starting Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: xampp

> XAMPP errors when starting Apache shutdown unexpectedly
>  Windows
> Version:  Home  64-bit
> XAMPP Version: 8.2.4
> Control Panel Version:
> 3.3.0  [ Compiled: Apr 6th 2021 ]
>  Portblocker Detected: mysqld.exe 
> XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306
>  Attempting to start Apache
> app...
>  Executing "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
>  Return code: 0
> Autostart aborted: MySQL is already running
>  Status change detected:
> running 
> Status change detected: stopped
> Error: Apache shutdown
> unexpectedly.

[XAMPP error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Dk1.png)

I have tried to reinstall 3 times and installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable runtime libraries and searched on line

Comment: There may possibly be a few things going on, but first check the Windows `Event Viewer` => `Windows Logs` => `Application` to see if there's any errors relative to Apache about the `shutdown unexpectedly` portion of the message. Also, what version of windows? 10, 11, or some other?

Comment: Thanks @PaulT. I found there was a conflict in the ports after I installed the windows passed hosting it worked